# Dplyr Transformation with gather

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I am trying to tidy one daraframe using dplyr, however I am having an issues with is.

Data that I have know looks like this:

```
.$AIC.x $k_neigh_numb.x $term              $estimate $std.error $Region
     <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  
 1   -445.               2 (Intercept)          12.5       0.0548  PRAHA  
 2   -445.               2 Rooms                 0.0820    0.00750 PRAHA  
 3   -445.               2 log(Meters)           0.684     0.0172  PRAHA  
 4   -445.               2 Mezone               -0.0398    0.0240  PRAHA  
 5   -700.               4 (Intercept)          12.5       0.0541  PRAHA
```

I need to insert "AIC.x" columns into term columns, so that final dataframe would look like this:

```
 $k_neigh_numb.x    $term              $estimate $std.error $Region
     <dbl>        <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  
 1   2            (Intercept)            12.5       0.0548  PRAHA  
 2   2              Rooms               0.0820      0.00750 PRAHA  
 3   2             log(Meters)           0.684       0.0172  PRAHA  
 4   2              Mezone             -0.0398      0.0240  PRAHA 
 5   2                AIC.x             -445.         NA     PRAHA
 6   4              (Intercept)          12.5       0.0541  PRAHA
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you want one `AIC.x` value per `k_neigh_numb.x` and `Region`.

Then we can make all the `AIC.x` rows:

```r
new_rows = data %>%
  group_by(k_neigh_numb.x, Region) %>%
  summarise(estimate = max(AIC.x)) %>%
  mutate(term = 'AIC.x',
         std.error = NA)
```

And append the new & existing rows together as follows:

```r
final = rbind(
  select(new_rows, c('k_neigh_numb.x', 'term', 'estimate', 'std.error', 'Region')),
  select(data,     c('k_neigh_numb.x', 'term', 'estimate', 'std.error', 'Region'))) %>%
  arrange(k_neigh_numb.x)
```

The select statements are deliberate to make the columns from the two tables line up. There are alternative functions that bind by column names should you need them.